# How to build basic tailwind classes autocomplete?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-3

I am building a little tailwind tool and need to build basic tailwind core classes autocomplete feature.
My first thought was to list all core classes in an array, but it is a very cumbersome process.
Are there are better ways to achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Looking for a similar thing. Let me know if you find something,